# Add variable to nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

Using R base, I would like to add a variable to a nested list where the variable changes for each nested list element. Below is an example. Thank you.

```
#CREATE EXAMPLE DATAFRAME
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))

#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))), ]))

#PRINT NESTED LIST
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))

#I WOULD LIKE TO SIMPLIFY THIS PART
DF[[1]][[1]] <- within(DF[[1]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[1]][[2]] <- within(DF[[1]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF[[2]][[1]] <- within(DF[[2]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[2]][[2]] <- within(DF[[2]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF[[3]][[1]] <- within(DF[[3]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[3]][[2]] <- within(DF[[3]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

#PRINT MODIFIED NESTED LIST
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))

#I AM SURPRISED THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))),]))
DF <- lapply(DF, function(x) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) within(x, GROUP <- t)))
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))
```

Comment: The `lapply` command should be modified to `lapply(DF, function(xs) lapply(1:2, function(t) within(xs[[t]], GROUP <- t)))`.

Comment: Edit on my original answer. You can define `GROUPS <- c(2014:2015)`, and use `lapply(DF, function(xs) lapply(1:2, function(t) within(xs[[t]], GROUP <- GROUPS[t])))` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may the second `lapply`:

```
DF <- lapply(DF, function(x) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) within(x, GROUP <- t)))
```

The `lapply`'s don't appear to be extracting the desired component from the large list object. The first `lapply` iterates over the top level of the list, extracting a two-element list object, `x`, each time. The second `lapply` then iterates over a vector, providing a scalar vector, `t`, each time. So, the next part gets a two-element list (`x`) each time instead of the desired (unnamed) data frame.

#### Solution

If the object has already been created, you can iterate over the elements directly instead of indexing the list elements.

```
#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))), ]))

edit_level2 <- function(df) {
    # figure out what the value of t should be based on the data.
    t <- as.integer(format(min(df$DATE), "%Y"))
    df$GROUP <- t
    return(df)
}

# iterate over the list object contents at *both* levels
DF <- lapply(DF, function(level1) lapply(level1, function(level2) edit_level2(level2)))
```

Note: this is similar to the solution presented by @Consistency in the comments--extracting the data frame is the issue.

#### Alternative

If you can you alter the code that is producing the list object, I suggest assigning the variable while creating the list object instead of modifying it afterwards (my original suggestion before edits).

```
#CREATE EXAMPLE DATAFRAME
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), 
                  DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))

#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {

    lapply(2014:2015, function(t) {

        first <- as.Date(paste(t,     "01", "01", sep = "-")) 
        last  <- as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-")) 

        # create a local data frame
        df <- DF[first <= DF$DATE & DF$DATE <= last, ]

        # modify the local data frame
        df$GROUP <- t

        # return the modified data frame
        df

    })

})
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do it

```
final_list<-list()
for(i in seq(1, length(DF))){

  new_list<-list()

  for(j in seq(1,length(DF[[i]]))){

    new_list[[j]]<-list(DF[[i]][[j]],GROUP=j)

  }
  final_list[[i]]<-new_list
}
```

Comment: This will be very very inefficient

Answer (score 7):

```
#CREATE EXAMPLE DATAFRAME
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))

#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))), ]))

#PRINT NESTED LIST
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))

#I WOULD LIKE TO SIMPLIFY THIS PART
DF[[1]][[1]] <- within(DF[[1]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[1]][[2]] <- within(DF[[1]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF[[2]][[1]] <- within(DF[[2]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[2]][[2]] <- within(DF[[2]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF[[3]][[1]] <- within(DF[[3]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF[[3]][[2]] <- within(DF[[3]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

#PRINT MODIFIED NESTED LIST
DF1 <- lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))
DF1

#I AM SURPRISED THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))),]))

GROUPS <- c(2014:2015)    

DF <- lapply(DF, function(xs) lapply(1:2, function(t) within(xs[[t]], GROUP <- GROUPS[t])))

DF2 <- lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))
DF2

all.equal(DF1, DF2)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?
Had to use package `dplyr` since it makes adding a new variable to the dataframes easier with `mutate_`.

```
library(dplyr) # if not installed, install with install.packages("dplyr")
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), 
DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))

#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, 
as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + 
i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))), ]))

# loop over the first list with lapply and then loop over the nested lists 
# and the desired GROUP values with mapply
DF <- lapply(DF, function(x) mapply(FUN = function(df,number){mutate_(df, 
"GROUP" = number)},x, 2014:2015, SIMPLIFY = F))

#PRINT NESTED LIST
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))
```

As to why your way was not working: Think about what `function(t) within(xs[[t]], GROUP <- GROUPS[t])` does. It does not return a dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

This can be also achieved using `Map` in order to `cbind` the dates. i.e.,

```
lapply(DF, function(i) Map(cbind, i, c(2014, 2015)))

#or to set the name of that column to 'id',

lapply(DF, function(i) Map(function(x, y) cbind(x, id = y), i, c(2014, 2015)))
```

However, If you don't mind flattening that list and keeping an extra id variable, you can use `tidyverse` to flatten and create the year id by graping the year from the first element of `DATE` from each data frame, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- DF %>% 
  flatten_df(.id = 'list_id') %>% 
  group_by(list_id) %>% 
  mutate(id = sub('-.*', '', DATE[1]))

#which will give,

# A tibble: 19,725 x 4
# Groups:   list_id [6]
#   list_id   NAME       DATE    id
#     <chr> <fctr>     <date> <chr>
# 1       1  FRANK 2014-01-01  2014
# 2       1   TONY 2014-01-01  2014
# 3       1     ED 2014-01-01  2014
# 4       1  FRANK 2014-01-02  2014
# 5       1   TONY 2014-01-02  2014
# 6       1     ED 2014-01-02  2014
# 7       1  FRANK 2014-01-03  2014
# 8       1   TONY 2014-01-03  2014
# 9       1     ED 2014-01-03  2014
#10       1  FRANK 2014-01-04  2014
# ... with 19,715 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I've got it. At least `all.equal` returns `TRUE`, though `identical` does not. Here it goes. Note that I've changed your df names a bit.

```
#CREATE EXAMPLE DATAFRAME
DF <- expand.grid(NAME = c("FRANK", "TONY", "ED"), DATE =    seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"))

#CREATE NESTED LIST
DF <- lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(2014:2015, function(t) DF[with(DF, as.Date(paste(t, "01", "01", sep = "-")) <= DATE & DATE <= as.Date(paste(t + i, "12", "31", sep = "-"))), ]))

#PRINT NESTED LIST
lapply(DF, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))

DF2 <- DF
#I WOULD LIKE TO SIMPLIFY THIS PART
DF2[[1]][[1]] <- within(DF2[[1]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF2[[1]][[2]] <- within(DF2[[1]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF2[[2]][[1]] <- within(DF2[[2]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF2[[2]][[2]] <- within(DF2[[2]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

DF2[[3]][[1]] <- within(DF2[[3]][[1]], GROUP <- 2014)
DF2[[3]][[2]] <- within(DF2[[3]][[2]], GROUP <- 2015)

#PRINT MODIFIED NESTED LIST
lapply(DF2, lapply, function(x) rbind(head(x), tail(x)))

### New code
DF3 <- DF
DF3 <- lapply(DF3, function(x) {
        lapply(2014:2015, function(t){
            within(x[[t - 2013]], GROUP <- t)
        })
    })
identical(DF2, DF3)
all.equal(DF2, DF3)
```